# Difference between nextXXX() and generateSeed() function in SecureRandom?

Tags: java, security, random, cryptography

What is the difference between functions nextXXX() - such as like `nextInt()`, `nextFloat()` and [`nextBytes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#nextBytes(byte[])) - and [`generateSeed(int numBytes): byte[]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#generateSeed(int)) in the [SecureRandom class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) of Java?

In what way does "the seed generation algorithm" in `generateSeed` differ from the secure random generator itself?

Comment: Have you read the JavaDocs? They seem quite clear to me ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for your comment, yes I read the java doc before posting this question. It would be really helpful, if you explain the difference

Comment: Why? It would be really helpful if you would explain what part of the Javadoc you don't understand. The difference is that they aren't the same.

Comment: @EJP Fixed the question, the JavaDoc isn't *that* clear on what generateSeed does in my opinion, "the seed generation algorithm" is not specified at all.

Comment: @owlstead Thanks for editing question for more clarity, yes I was looking for the seed generation algorithm

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`generateSeed()` does not use any bytes generated by the random number generator. Instead, it is just a **pass through to the entropy source that the `SecureRandom` implementation uses to seed itself** when and **if it is seeding itself**.

---

So for instance calling the following code on an Oracle provided Java SE:

```
// initSeed is just zero valued bytes
byte[] initSeed = new byte[16];

SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
secureRandom.setSeed(initSeed);

byte[] seed = secureRandom.generateSeed(16);

byte[] data = new byte[16];
secureRandom.nextBytes(data);

System.out.printf("Seed: %s%n", Hex.toHexString(seed));
System.out.printf("Data: %s%n", Hex.toHexString(data));
```

Will actually give back different values for `seed`, and always the same value for `data`. In other words, the `generateSeed` uses the operating system to ask for 16 bytes of entropy, while the random number generator is only seeded with the `initSeed` and thus will always generate the same stream of *pseudo* random numbers.

**Warning**: this is just to illustrate the point; you should **not** rely on any `SecureRandom` instance to return anything but random bytes. The behavior with regards to `setSeed` differs per implementation. The Oracle `"SHA1PRNG"` provider uses it as the only seed, others may choose to mix it into the state of the PRNG (for instance later Android implementations will always generate random data).

Answer (score 3):

Random number functions depend on an initial value from which they generate a sequence of random numbers (read up on PRNG - Pseudo Random Number Generation).  The `next` functions will return the next number generated from that initial value (the seed).  `generateSeed()` will generate a new initial value for a PRNG to use.

Comment: Doesn't restart anything on my machine. You can use it to start up or seed *another* generator though.

Comment: This was meant to be a really generic answer, sorry.  It seemed like the OP didn't quite understand the concept, rather than the implementation of it.

Comment: OK, but that last line is simply not correct, it doesn't restart anything by itself. Happy to upvote if you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, `nextXYZ()` and `generateSeed()` do the exactly same thing, most often

`SecureRandom.nextBytes()` and `SecureRandom.generateSeed()` actually are just thin wrappers that forward the call to `SecureRandomSpi.engineGenerateSeed()` and `SecureRandomSpi.engineNextBytes()`, respectively, which contain the actual implementation.

The concrete implementation of `SecureRandomSpi` depends on the selected algorithm, of course! However, for the *default* SecureRandom algorithm on the Windows platform (i.e. `"Windows-PRNG"`), we can see from the source code that `engineNextBytes()` and `engineGenerateSeed()` do the exactly same thing: They ***both*** call a *native* method named `PRNG.generateSeed()`, which is a C++ function that ends up calling the Win32 API function `CryptGenRandom()` from the **OS**

See here for details:

- https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/b3fec6b5f32c338ae1a84dd20bdcbd3d9b7186f3/src/jdk.crypto.mscapi/windows/classes/sun/security/mscapi/PRNG.java#L96
- https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/b3fec6b5f32c338ae1a84dd20bdcbd3d9b7186f3/src/jdk.crypto.mscapi/windows/native/libsunmscapi/security.cpp#L331
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom

---

The implementation of the `"NativePRNG"` algorithm, which is the *default* algorithm on Linux/Unix and MacOS, is a bit more convoluted. But, essentially, `engineNextBytes()` and `engineGenerateSeed()` once again ***both*** end up in the same method – which is `RandomIO.readFully()`. *That* method simply reads the "random" bytes from an `InputStream`, which has been associated with `/dev/[u]random`, i.e. the **kernel** random number source.

See here for details:

- https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/unix/classes/sun/security/provider/NativePRNG.java#L36
- https://linux.die.net/man/4/urandom

---

All of the other `[Secure]Random.nextXYZ()` methods, such as `nextInt()`, `nextLong()` or `nextDouble()`, call an *internal* method named `next()`, which provides the request number of random *bits*. And, **not** much surprising, the `next()` method ends up calling `nextBytes()` – and therefor, in case of `SecureRandom`, invokes `SecureRandomSpi.engineNextBytes()`